# Кнопка Back, в AsyncTask при использовании WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-asynctask

Открываю ссылки в    WebView, после нажатия кнопки Back не возвращает на предыдущую ссылку, просто белый экран

```
public class ArticleView extends Activity {

String linkArticle;

ProgressBar progressBar;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_view);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

    linkArticle = getIntent().getStringExtra("link");

    Log.d("myLogs", "getLinkList in ArticleView: " + linkArticle);

    new NewThread(linkArticle).execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    } else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String titleArticle = "";
    String contentArticle = "";

    String link;

    Elements content;

    Document doc = null;

    NewThread(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Log.d("myLogs", link);

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();

            content = doc.select(".blog-node-top");
            titleArticle = content.outerHtml();

            content = doc.select(".text");
            contentArticle = content.outerHtml();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://dev.by", 
                titleArticle + contentArticle, "text/html", "en_US", null);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Не стесняйтесь, покажите код.

Comment: А для чего вы используете AsyncTask?

Comment: @miha_dev работа с сетью в главном потоке запрещена и вызывает exсeption, необходимо выносить в отдельный поток

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо в вашей Activity добавить код:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || !webView.canGoBack()) {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    webView.goBack();
    return true;
}
```

также вы можете использовать этот

```
 public void onBackPressed (){
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();       
    }
    else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: пробовал эти варианты, не работает, спасибо